# Cannot resolve symbol 'TextRecognizer'

Tags: android, text-recognition

Following the simple steps from here: https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/text-recognition/android#java

I cannot even compile the app.

So I do what's in "before you begin" section:

I check in my code (build.gradle file, the one that says "Project:"):

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.1"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

In my code build.gradle file, the one that says "Module":

```
dependencies {

implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-mlkit-text-recognition:17.0.0' }
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.textrectest">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.TextRecTest">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.mlkit.vision.DEPENDENCIES"
            android:value="ocr" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Then, I proceed with the next section.

In my project:

```
package com.example.textrectest;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    private Button btnMain;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btnMain = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnMain);
        btnMain.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "hola", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
        
        TextRecognizer recognizer = TextRecognition.getClient(TextRecognizerOptions.DEFAULT_OPTIONS);
    }
}
```

But then, Android Studio says (the code editor itself shows me he doesn't like what I'm doing, highlighting "TextRecognizer" with a red color):

> cannot find symbol
> TextRecognizer

So what I'm doing wrong? I guess it's something completely dumb but I can't figure out what is it.

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: Try `invalidate cache and restart`  i.e `File -> Invalidate Caches  ->  Restart`

Comment: It worked. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

As @Noah commented, the "invalidate Caches / Restart" option did it for me, and now I'm able to import the modules I need for the code to run (I guess I could have imported them manually before, but I didn't know what modules I needed, and the IntelliJ thing didn't recommended it to me because of the cache, I guess).

Comment: I think you are supposed to upvote my comment

Comment: My bad, done. Thank you